# Terraform default map values

Tags: variables, merge, terraform

Does the default value of the variable map merges with data I provide to the terraform?

Sample variables.tf:

```
variable "foo" {
  type = map
  default = {
    lorem = "ipsum"
    dolor = "sit"
  }
}
```

And foo.tfvars provided:

```
foo = {
  dolor = "changed"
  amet = "consectetur"
}
```

Will `${foo.lorem}` still exist?

Will `${foo.dolor}` be "changed"?

Will `${foo.amet}` be available?

Comment: Which version of Terraform are you using?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR 0.12.20

Answer (score 11):

No, there is no merging behavior. If you set an explicit value for a variable then the default is not used at all.

If you need to merge with other values then you can use [the `merge` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/merge.html) to write that explicitly:

```
variable "foo" {
  type    = map(string)
  default = {}
}

locals {
  foo = merge(
    tomap({
      lorem = "ipsum"
      dolor = "sit"
    }),
    var.foo,
  )
}
```

With the above configuration, elsewhere in the module you can refer either to `var.foo` to get the exact value the caller provided or to `local.foo` to get the result of merging the caller's map with your map of default values.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify, if you'd specified your tfvars file, you'd get:

```
${foo.lorem} = "Error: Missing map element"

${foo.dolor} = "changed"

${foo.amet}  = "consectetur"
```